# Extracting fields from XML using mule splitter or xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, mule, esb

Hi below is my input XML I want to spit the XML by row:

```
<root>
  <row>
    <Product>abc</Product>
    <price>20</price>
    <discount>10%</discount>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Product>def</Product>
    <price>120</price>
    <discount>11%</discount>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Product>ghi</Product>
    <price>210</price>
    <discount>5%</discount>
  </row>
</root>
```

The output XML should look like below:

First XML

```
<trx>
    <Product>abc</Product>
    <discount>10%</discount>
</trx>
```

Second XML

```
<trx>
    <Product>def</Product>
    <discount>11%</discount>
</trx>
```

And so on.

Do I have to use splitter or xslt what will be the xslt code to achieve this. I need to change the root name and also remove the field price from the original XML

Comment: To do this in XSLT, you will need an XSLT 2.0 processor or one that supports an extension element allowing multiple documents to be output as a result of a single transformation.

Comment: So is it possible  do it with mule and if i use multiple documents i can i make it to go through the flow

Comment: I am afraid I know nothing about Mule. If it uses the Apache Xalan XSLT processor, then the answer is no. But if you are using Java, then you should able to switch to Saxon, I think.

Comment: I found the answer thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I found was using a splitter and then using a data mapper to change the structure.
So I used the splitter first and using xpath I took the row

```
#[xpath('/root/*')]
```

Then i used the data mapper to change it to my desired format